# Handle lists in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a very simple SQL table structure:

Users:

| id | name | scope_ids |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | alex | 1,2 |
| 2 | peter | 1 |
| 3 | xyz | 3,1 |

Scopes:

| scope_id | scope |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | a |
| 2 | b |
| 3 | c |

I would like the scopes column to be somehow "coupled" to the scopes table. It feels wrong just setting the users->scope_ids column to a string like `a,b`. This screams like inconsistency among tables using the same scopes and someone can just add arbitrary scope names.

**In short**: Is there a way to elegantly handle lists as column values in SQL (In my specific case, SQLite).

Comment: You should use a many-to-many table instead.

Comment: Ok thanks for the explanation. I mean the table relation you see IS what I tried. This is a code independent question, so there isn't really any code to provide. I'm not asking about some query. My problem is that the structure I tried seems like there has to be a better way...

Answer (score 0):

I would use a mapping table to add the many-to-many relationship.

For your example:

1. drop the column `scope_ids` from the `Users` table.
2. add a new table `UserScope` with two columns `userId` and `scopeId` - with a combined primary key over the two columns.

```
userId  scopeId
------  -------
1       1
1       2
2       1
3       1
3       3
```

... and then use joined queries to handle your data.